# ant design: reactjs: component: how to access record

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
        const components = {
            body: {
                row: EditableRow,
                cell: EditableCell,
            },
        };



        <Table
            components={components}
        ....



        const EditableRow = ({ index, ...props }) => {
            ...HOW TO ACCESS record here
            return (
               .....
            )
        };
```

In ant reactjs how to access the record inside a component.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `index` inside EditableRow function which can be used to pick datasource array item.

Refer example:- https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row